# Import or load svn repo from older svn fomat

Tags: svn

I had a hard drive crash on a server with several svn repos on it. I managed to copy the directory that contained all the data /var/svn/ off before it was completely unreadable.

I want to load the repos with full history onto a new server. Whenever I try to use svnadmin dump, for example

```
svnadmin dump /path/repo1 > repo1.dump
```

I get the error

```
svnadmin: E000002: Can't open file 'neon_server_data/svn_all/svn/dft/format': No such file or directory
```

I guess the format has changed in the newer version of svn. newly created repos have a format file containing the number 5.

I also tried the update options which did not work, and copying all the 'db' into a new repo which did not work.

I am using svn, version 1.8.8 (r1568071). I don't know which version was running on the older computer.

Thanks